# What is the different between adding to images together using "+" and the add() method in Opencv in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

So imagine we have two images: img1 and img2.
when adding these two together using + or cv2.add() we get different results. Why is that? How are they different?

```
img = img1 + img2
img = cv2.add(img1, img2)
```

Answer (score 4):

from the opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html):

> Image Addition You can add two images with the OpenCV function,
> cv.add(), or simply by the numpy operation res = img1 + img2. Both
> images should be of same depth and type, or the second image can just
> be a scalar value.
>
> Note There is a difference between OpenCV addition and Numpy addition.
> OpenCV addition is a saturated operation while Numpy addition is a
> modulo operation. For example, consider the below sample:

```
x = np.uint8([250])
>>> y = np.uint8([10])
>>> print( cv.add(x,y) ) # 250+10 = 260 => 255 
[[255]]
>>> print( x+y )          # 250+10 = 260 % 256 = 4 
[4]
```

> This will be more visible when
> you add two images. Stick with OpenCV functions,
> because they will provide a better result.

Comment: Why does x+y take the moduo of 256? Where did 256 come from?

Comment: Not sure but I guess it has to have with integer arithmetic in numpy

Comment: 256 is the number of representable values in 8 bit => 0 to 255

Comment: This is the result of overflow.  If you go beyond 255, it will do modulo 255.  This is expected behaviour for limited precision numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your `img1` and `img2` variables are of `dtype == np.uint8`:
`img1 + img2` is `numpy` addition, which is a `modulo` operation, whereas `cv2.add(img1 + img2)` is `saturated` operation.

`np.uint8` is 8-bit unsigned integer (from 0 to 255), so if the resultant is out of bounds, then `numpy` and `opencv` handle that differently. For example:

```
>>> img1 = np.uint8([250])
>>> img2 = np.uint8([50])

# numpy
>>> img1 + img2
array([44], dtype=uint8)  # (250 + 50) % 256 = 44
# it takes the modulo of 256

# opencv
>>> cv2.add(img1, img2)
array([[255]], dtype=uint8)  # min(max(0, (250 + 50)), 255) = 255 or np.clip(300, 0, 255)
# it saturates to 255
```

For `np.uint8` the range would be `(0, 4294967295)`