# How does imagechops.add_modulo function work?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics, signal-processing

Below function should output black as per add_modulo definition. (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#functions)
When white and green given as input, black should be the output. But yellow outputted.
([255, 255, 255] and [0, 255, 0] is given as input) Is there something I miscalculated?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

im1= Image.open(r'.\white.jpg')
im2= Image.open(r'.\green.jpg')

result = ImageChops.add_modulo(im1, im2)

plt.imshow(result)
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633820/2836621

Comment: I read it. It says: Add two images, without clipping the result. out = ((image1 + image2) % MAX) When white [255, 255, 255] and green [0, 255, 0] added with add_modulo, it is [255, 510, 255]. When modulo is applied, this becomes black [0, 0 ,0]. But yellow [255, 255, 0] comes down as output. This doesn't make sense. @Mark.Setchell

Comment: % MAX =% 255 is my guess.